# When do the gradients exist in a Reinforcement Learning setting?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am getting properly stuck into reinforcement learning and [I am currently reading the review paper by Kober et al. (2013)](http://www.ias.tu-darmstadt.de/uploads/Publications/Kober_IJRR_2013.pdf).

And there is one constant feature that I cannot get my head around, but which is mentioned a lot, not just in this paper, but others too; namely the existence of gradients.

In section 2.2.2. they say:

> The approach is very straightforward and even applicable to policies
>   that are not differentiable.

w.r.t. to *finite difference gradients*.

What does it mean to say that the gradients exist and indeed, how do we know that they exist? When wouldn't they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient doesn't exist / isn't well-defined for non-differentiable functions.  What they mean by that statement is that there is an *analogous* version of gradients that can be used, instead of the gradient.

### Discrete functions

In the discrete case, [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) are the discrete version of derivatives.  The derivative of a single-variable continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $df/dx$; the partial difference (a discrete derivative) of a single-variable discrete function $g:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is $\Delta f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by

$$\Delta f(x) = f(x+1)-f(x).$$

There's a similar thing that's analogous to a gradient.  If we have a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables, the gradient consists of partial derivatives $\partial f / \partial x$ and $\partial f / \partial y$.  In the discrete case $g(x,y)$, we have partial differences $\Delta_x f$ and $\Delta_y f$, where

$$\Delta_x f(x,y) = f(x+1,y) - f(x)$$

and similarly for $\Delta_y f$.

### Continuous functions

If you have a continuous function that is not differentiable at some points (so the gradient does not exist), sometimes you can use the [subgradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative#The_subgradient) in lieu of the gradient.